# Multiplying an array with a floating number

Tags: ruby

The method `Array#*` takes an integer:

```
thumbs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
thumbs = thumbs*2
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

How can I multiply an array to any floating number and not just an integer? For example, I would expect the following result:

```
thumbs = thumbs*1.5
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: How would you do [*1..10]*1.01?

Comment: Sorry, can't understand what you mean.

Comment: what is the result you're expecting in your last example?

Comment: The current array plus the half of the same again, something like this `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: Updated my answer, it now has a working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array = [*1..10]
fraction = 1.5
thumbs = array.cycle.take((array.length * fraction).floor)
```

Depending on how you want to handle fractional cases, you can use `ceil` or `round` instead of `floor`.

Comment: That's a very nice solution. Why is the .to_a required?

Comment: What `.to_a`? ;) I assumed `take` would return another `Enumerable` but it actually returns an array.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer 1

Simply because `Array * x` is only defined to work with an integer.

### Answer 2

Because in some cases, it is unclear what output to expect from this. For example

```
[1,2,3]*1.5
```

Should this output `[1,2]` or `[1]`?

### Possible Solution

You can define your own method, though:

```
class Array
  alias_method :old_mult , :'*'            # remember, how old multiplication worked

  def * other                              # override * method
    result = old_mult(other.floor)         # multiply with floored factor
    end_index = (size * (other % 1)).round # convert decimal points to array index
    result + self[0...end_index]           # add elements corresponding to decimal points
  end
end

p [1,2] * 1
p [1,2,3] * 2
p [1,2,3,4,5] * 1.5
p [1,2,3,4,5,6] * 1.5
```

this outputs

```
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method and do whatever you want:

```
def arr_times(f, arr)
  i = float.to_i
  arr*i + arr[0..(((f-i)*arr.length).floor)]
end
```